# Get a hypervisor name from its obj_id while in a table_action

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-horizon

I am trying to make some changes to the OpenStack Horizon UI but am running into some issues I am hoping someone can help with.  I am currently doing some work on the admin->hypervisor page and am trying to add a button that lets me perform actions on the selected hypervisors (using a table_actions to do this).  To do this I have created my own table_action that is being defined in the Meta of the AdminHypervisors class.

I have the part of the code for selecting my hypervisors working from the page and can get my form to load... Here is my issue... The action(self,request, obj_id) function that my action implements gets passed the obj_id of the hypervisor and to do my work I need the hypervisor host name. So I need some way to translate this ID into a host name...

Here is my table_action class

```
class DeploySelection(tables.BatchAction):
    name = "deploy"
    action_present = _("Deploy")
    action_past = _("Deploy selected selection to ")
    data_type_singular = _("selection")
    data_type_plural = _("selections")
    classes = ("btn-deploy")

    def action(self, request, obj_id):
        LOG.warn(_("obj_id == %s") % obj_id)
        #convert obj_id here and get hypervsior name
        #do work based using hypervisor name here
```

in this example, obj_id will look like '2'

**TL&DR:**  I need to find how a function or way to take a hypervisors id and get back the "hypervisor_hostname" that is associated with that hypervisor.

Comment: got an example of what you are getting for a hypervisor id?  is it a uuid specific enough to do a lookup for the host that hypervisor id is attached to?  or is it just an id for a list of possible hypervisors?

Comment: edited to provide info...